# Valid Parentheses C# Stack

Tags: c#, stack

this is one of the best solution in c# for this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/) on leetcode. Can someone explain me why the Stack gets empty at the end without using Pop()?

```
            bool testen(string s)
            {
                // Get ready initial state (enforce element type)
                var k = new Stack<char>();
                // Evaluate each character for potential mismatch 
                foreach (char c in s)
                {
                    // Push closing round bracket onto the stack
                    if (c == '(') { k.Push(')'); continue; }
                    // Push closing curly bracket onto the stack
                    if (c == '{') { k.Push('}'); continue; }
                    // Push closing square bracket onto the stack
                    if (c == '[') { k.Push(']'); continue; }
                    // Look out for imbalanced strings or mismatches
                    if (k.Count == 0 || c != k.Pop()) return false;
                }
                // Empty stack means string is valid and invalid otherwise
                return k.Count == 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack doesn't 'get empty at the end'; it is empty when the string provided does meet any of the criteria for populating it.

Basically, `k` is a mirror image of `c`, which in turn is a character representation of `s`. If `s` does not contain `(`, `{`, or `[`, then `k` will never get populated, and thus `k` will return empty, as it is set to be an empty Stack initially with `var k = new Stack<char>()`.

The fourth conditional there is merely ensuring that the length of `k` is equal to the length of `c`. This conditional is entirely redundant, as the outer `return` statement will return `false` if `k.Count` is `0`.